# Solving a non-linear system of equations given $1000$ data points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear

I have a vector of $1000$ data points saved in a vector $y$ and I need to solve a set of non-linear equations. Since I cannot write down all $1000$ values, I will assume that I have the following data

```
y={0.010006, 0.132207, 0.9594, 2.5454, 5.13752, 8.2837, 18.89587, 54.96714, 177.053, 477.268, 1833.817}

t=1;

y[i+1]-a*exp(t^2*(i-k)^2/s^2)=0  (*this is for i=0,1,....*)
```

> How can I find the parameters $a$, $k$ and $s$?

I am able to use `Solve` or `NSolve` etc. My main problem is not being able to let mathematica define these $1000$ equations automatically.

Is there any generic way to let mathematica do these function definitions automatically without my manual contributions?

Comment: `eqns = Thread[y - a*Exp[t^2*(Range[0, Length[y] - 1] - k)^2/s^2] == 0]`?

Comment: @kglr yes! thank you. you can post an answer.

Comment: `Table[y[[i + 1]] - a*Exp[t^2*(i - k)^2/s^2] == 0, {i, 0, 
  Length[y] - 1}]`

Comment: Are you trying to fit the data in order to extract `a`, `k` and `s`?

Comment: Please give a smaller example of input and what exactly is wanted. What is shown above is not terribly clear.

Comment: @CarlWoll yes I am trying to fit data optimally for example with non-linear least squares, etc. I am interested in different methods.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau it is overdetermined system of non-linear equations. I would like to solve such a system using non-linear least squares or with some other iterative methods. Lets say the method which minimizes $(y-s exp(....))^2$.

Comment: Looks like a task for `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks for the comment. It is my bad. t=-1 is the correct choice. Then it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
y = RandomInteger[100, 10];
eqns = Thread[y - a*Exp[t^2*(Range[0, Length[y] - 1] - k)^2/s^2] == 0];

TeXForm[Column @ eqns]
```

> $\small\begin{array}{l}
>  6-a e^{\frac{k^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  8-a e^{\frac{(1-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  85-a e^{\frac{(2-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  71-a e^{\frac{(3-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  20-a e^{\frac{(4-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  44-a e^{\frac{(5-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  96-a e^{\frac{(6-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  37-a e^{\frac{(7-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  91-a e^{\frac{(8-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
>  13-a e^{\frac{(9-k)^2}{s^2}}=0 \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: I used NSolve[eqns, {a, k, s}]  and I got an empty set...

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, apparently there is no solution (equations are inconsistent). You might want to try `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try.

Comment: I just checked. There is a little problem. There, the function to fit is not changing with the data but in my case the fitted model is changing with the data index through $(i-k)^2$

Comment: @Seyhmus, use `data=Transpose[{Range[Length@y], y}]` as the first argument in `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Great. Thank you once again.